# Can one experience be counted twice in resume?

Tags: resume

I worked at a company for 4 years. In the first 3.5, I was an individual contributor (IC). In the last 0.5 year I was 50% IC and 50% leading few junior ICs.

In my resume, I want to have two sections: one for work experience and one for leadership experience. For the former, when I list my IC role, is it OK to put 4 years for the date, and for the latter, put 0.5 years for the date? I am not sure if this may sound misleading as the dates for the two "positions" would be overlapping...

Comment: It's ok to have overlapping dates on a resume. Many people will often work in more than one job/ assignment at one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Just put 2 roles under the company with appropriate dates.

If you have leadership results in the 1st 3.5 years feel free to put that under the IC role.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear to me whether you're planning on putting down dates or duration in your resume but I think splitting up your work experience into separate individual contribution and leadership sections would be confusing even without the overlap.

You can include the fact that you lead junior co-workers for half a year as a bullet point (or points, depending on what you want to say) under your role at that company.

If you want to talk more about your experience leading a small team of juniors in your job application, a cover letter is a good place to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Recruiter here!! :)

I would add the two experiences under the same company and not overthink it :)

Like this:

Company XYZ - 2010-2014

Leadership role - responsibilities...

Individual contributor - responsibilities...

Recruiters and employers don't care about dates that much... the content of the resume is truly what matters :)